# how to specify field name on refrofit2 multipart post request

Tags: android, api, retrofit2, vk

I'm trying to upload image to vk.com. I have the next
 [documentation](https://vk.com/dev/upload_files?f=2.%20Uploading%20Photos%20on%20User%20Wall).
As per it, I must send images in a post field `photo`. However I cannot get a clue how to set it with `retrofit2`. 
My current code:

```
String fileName = file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().lastIndexOf("."));
RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), file);
MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(fileName, file.getName(), requestFile);
Response<UploadFileResponse> response = wallpostService.upload(url, body).execute();

@Multipart
    @POST("{url}")
    Call<UploadFileResponse> upload(
            @Path("url") String url,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part file
    );
```

Therefore, I'm constantly getting 403 error..

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44951205/6021469

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan thanks, but my question is deeper than just sending multipart request

Comment: Your request is understood but refused by WS. It might be several reasons and the most one is authorization.

Comment: @EmreAktürk I'm obtaining url on the previous step using access token so if have this url - i'm authorized